# Multiple table tabs with persistent URL

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to pull in information from a table of businesses - company names, addresses, phone numbers - that are formatted similarly. I'm able to pull in that information through IMPORTHTML (and IMPORTXML) for the first page of results when I load the URL. However, there are multiple tabs of the table under the same URL.

How do I write the IMPORTHTML formula so it will pull in relevant information from the other table tabs?

URL (in A2 of Google Sheets): https://www.tcia.org/TCIA/Directories/FindQualifiedTreeCare.aspx?State=MD

Formula:

```
=IMPORTHTML(A2,"table",3)
```

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, that is not possible in Google Sheets because the URL is the same for all page views

[image]

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @player0, this is not possible because URL is same for every `Page`.

Take a look at javascript function for each links

For the Page 1:

```js
__doPostBack(
  'ctl01$TemplateBody$WebPartManager1$gwpste_container_MemberResults$ciMemberResults$gvSearchResults',
  'Page$1')
```

For the Page 2:

```js
__doPostBack(
  'ctl01$TemplateBody$WebPartManager1$gwpste_container_MemberResults$ciMemberResults$gvSearchResults',
  'Page$2')
```

For the Page 3:

```js
__doPostBack(
  'ctl01$TemplateBody$WebPartManager1$gwpste_container_MemberResults$ciMemberResults$gvSearchResults',
  'Page$3')
```

So when you put this function in your browser console, you will be redirected to corresponded page.

> Is it possible do add this function into location bar so we can get a direct URL?

**It is not possible for security reasons**, browsers block this practice in general.

> Any ways to bypass it?

Here are the steps what I would do:

1. You can use *python browser driver* to simulate user behavior in browser
2. Web scrape the data to your local machine
3. Upload data using [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values)
4. Parse it how ever you want with [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)

I hope it helps